# Why customized django login form thows takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-login

I was trying to customized django login form. but it throws error like this **TypeError at /login/ __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**. I have created my own form and not using django built in forms. My Project structure looks like this

```
project_name
 apps
  app1
  app2
static
templates
  app1
    login.html
  app2
```

app1 contains the basic home, login, signup template file
**url.py** file inside app1 looks like this

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import home
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name  = "basics"
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', home, name="home_page"),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView,{'template_name': 'basics/login.html'}, name="login")
]
```

**login.html** file resides under templates/app1/login.html and its template looks like this.

```
{% extends 'basics/home.html' %}

{% block body %}
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/login.js' %}"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto">
            <div class="card card-signin my-5">
                <div class="card-body" style="background-color: azure">
                    <h3 class="card-title text-center">Log In</h3>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p class="text-center">How did you signup?</p>
                    {{ error }}
                    <div class="main" id="mainForm">
                        <br>
                        <form class="form form-group" method="POST" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input name ="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" required="required">
                            </br>
                            <input name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password"
                                required="required">
                            </br>
                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-dark btn-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            <br>
                            <a href="#" class="text-center" id="backlink">back</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dummybutton">
                        </br>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-block emailbutton" style="background-color: skyblue">Email</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-block facebookbutton" style="background-color:aqua">Facebook</button>
                        </br>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">Dont have a Profile? <a href="#">Sign up </a>now</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

**view.py** file looks like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as login_check

def home(request):
    result = {}
    return render(request, 'basics/home.html', result)

def login(request):
    result = {'error': 'No error'}
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["passsword"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login_check(request, user)
            redirect('home/')
        else:
            result = {'error':'Invalid User'}
            return render(request, 'basics/home.html', result)            
    return render(request, 'basics/home.html', result)
```

Comment: Replace `auth_views.LoginView` with `auth_views.LoginView.as_view()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hey Thanks it worked. one more question i want to cleaned the data before processing is there any way to clean the data without built in form.

Comment: what do you mean with "*clean up data*"?

Comment: I mean to use built in method like is_valid(), cleaned_data() on form object. Is there any way to clean the form data before query the database with using built in forms

Comment: You can use `form.cleaned_data['username'] and `form.cleaned_data['password']` yes, this can indeed clean the data. If you have no form then there is not much cleaning to do, since it depends on the form fields how to clean data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `LoginView` the wrong way, you need to add `.as_view()` to convert the class-based view to a function, like:

```
app_name  = 'basics'

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', home, name="home_page"),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='basics/login.html'), name="login")
]
```